The Unexpected Read-Only Error in Tinymce with nextjs
I have a nextjs project that required rich text editor and I choose tinymce, the problem is when I tried follow the doc it just gave me an error even though I'm using gpl license in the code anyone have an idea on how to fix this?, Thanks!!

here's my code:


edit: I'm not exactly following the official doc because there's no official code for tsx, I follow this instead
edit2: fixed now by just replicate node_modules/tinymce to public and added id="Editor" licenseKey="gpl" tinymceScriptSrc="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" to Editor component

